# Creating nuget package in VS 2015, package tab not available

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to create a nuget package from a class library project in Visual studio 2015, In Project properties ---> **package tab is not available/ visible**.

IN the package tab we define the nuget package details.

Is it because of the **visual studio 2015 issue** or should I look for it somewhere else ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VS2015** IDE does not support that.

The **Package** tab(**Generate Nuget package on build**) is the feature of [new sdk style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format) lib project.(`Net Core` and `Net Standard`).

**And** the new sdk projects are released since **VS2017** while **VS2015** does not support it **--** You can not create any `Net Core` or `Net Standard` projects and only the `Net Framework` lib projects which does not contain the feature.

So you should use **VS2017** or later VS and then create a `Net Core` or `Net Standard` lib project and then you can find it.